# Make a page with 3 headings that appear after references and are listet in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, scrbook

I am using scrbook.
The problem is that when I am using \chapter, it creates a new page for every chapter. But I want all 3 chapter headings, each with one short paragraph, to be on the same page. And I don't want that it takes so much space before the heading. I want to use custom spacing. And it should be listed in the TOC without a number. Furthermore, I only want this behavior on this page, not the entire document.

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use KOMA-Script commands `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry` and `\DeclareNewSectionCommand` to define a new heading on chapter level but with section style.

```latex
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  level:=chapter,
  indent:=chapter,
  beforeskip:=chapter,
  numwidth:=chapter
]{chapter}{specialChap}
\DeclareNewSectionCommand[
  style=section,
  level=\chapternumdepth,
  beforeskip=3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex,% default section value used
  afterskip=2.3ex plus .2ex,% default section value used
  afterindent=false,
  runin=false,
  font=\usekomafont{chapter}
]{specialChap}
\makeatletter
\let\c@specialChap\c@chapter% use chapter counter
\let\lc@specialChap\lc@chapter% use reset list of chapter
\makeatother
```

For the page header you can use either

```latex
\renewcommand{\specialChapmark}[1]\markboth{\specialChapmarkformat#1}{}}
```

or if you load package `scrlayer-scrpage`

```latex
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark*{specialChap}
```

With KOMA-Script option `headings=optiontoheadandtoc` option `nonumber=true` can be used to get unnumbered headings.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[headings=optiontoheadandtoc]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  level:=chapter,
  indent:=chapter,
  beforeskip:=chapter,
  numwidth:=chapter
]{chapter}{specialChap}
\DeclareNewSectionCommand[
  style=section,
  level=\chapternumdepth,
  beforeskip=3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex,
  afterskip=2.3ex plus .2ex,
  afterindent=false,
  runin=false,
  font=\usekomafont{chapter}
]{specialChap}
\makeatletter
\let\c@specialChap\c@chapter
\let\lc@specialChap\lc@chapter
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\specialChapmark}[1]{\markboth{\specialChapmarkformat#1}{}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Normal chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{A section}
\lipsum[2-6]

\cleardoublepage
\specialChap[nonumber=true]{First special chapter}
\lipsum[7]
\specialChap[nonumber=true]{Second special chapter}
\lipsum[8]
\specialChap[nonumber=true]{Third special chapter}
\lipsum[9]

\chapter{Normal chapter}
\lipsum[10-15]
\end{document}
```

or

```latex
\documentclass[headings=optiontoheadandtoc]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  level:=chapter,
  indent:=chapter,
  beforeskip:=chapter,
  numwidth:=chapter
]{chapter}{specialChap}
\DeclareNewSectionCommand[
  style=section,
  level=\chapternumdepth,
  beforeskip=3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex,
  afterskip=2.3ex plus .2ex,
  afterindent=false,
  runin=false,
  font=\usekomafont{chapter}
]{specialChap}
\makeatletter
\let\c@specialChap\c@chapter
\let\lc@specialChap\lc@chapter
\makeatother
\automark*{specialChap}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Normal chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{A section}
\lipsum[2-6]

\cleardoublepage
\specialChap[nonumber=true]{First special chapter}
\lipsum[7]
\specialChap[nonumber=true]{Second special chapter}
\lipsum[8]
\specialChap[nonumber=true]{Third special chapter}
\lipsum[9]

\chapter{Normal chapter}
\lipsum[10-15]
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Very nice solution! It is fascinating how many paths bring the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

This template will help you get started.

The command `\specialChap` will simulate a chapter heading, use custom spacing, insert the entry in the ToC as an unnumbered chapter, but will stay in the same page. It will also generate a link in the ToC.

**UPDATE** after follow-up question

**(1)** Added `References` before "special chapters" to check for the absence of dragged-in headings from previous chapter.

**(2)** Added `hyperref` and generated the correct links in the ToC, both for `References` and the "special chapters"

[image: a]

[image: b]

Compile as pdflatex + pdflatex + bibtex + pdflatex + pdflatex

```
\documentclass[open=right]{scrbook}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % only for dummy text
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\specialChap}[1]{% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\thispagestyle{plain}   
\setkomafont{minisec}{\usekomafont{chapter}}%
\phantomsection% make a link in ToC
\minisec{#1}% simil chapter headings
\vspace*{1ex}% below space
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}% add to ToC at chapter level
}

%%******************************** References
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}   
    @article{Carlson2011, 
        author = {Carlson, Nicholas},
        booktitle = {Businessinsider.com},
        title = {{How Many Users Does Twitter REALLY Have?}},
        note = {Available online at  \url{www.businessinsider.com/chart-of-the-day-how-many-users-does-twitter-really-have-2011-31/3}},
        year = {2011},
    }   
    
    @book{companion94,
        author       = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
        title        = {The \LaTeX\ {Companion}},
        year         = {1994},
        edition      = 1,
        publisher    = {Addison-Wesley},
        location     = {Reading, Mass.},
        pagetotal    = 528,
    }
    
\end{filecontents*}
%***********************************************
    
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{This chapter is fine}
1. \kant[1-6]

See \cite{Carlson2011, companion94}.

\cleardoublepage % needed <<<
\phantomsection % make a link in ToC
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}% add to ToC at chapter level
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}%
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\cleardoublepage% needed <<<
\specialChap{First special}
1. \kant[1]
\specialChap{Second special}
9. \kant[9]
\specialChap{Third special}
11. \kant[11]  

\chapter{This chapter is also fine} 
\kant[4-8]
\end{document}
```

Comment: My problem is that there is still 'References' in the Header of the new chapters, and when I click on the new entries in the TOC, I get to 'References.'

Comment: @the return of the thesis Thre are no "References" nor links in my example. Please test it  alone. As you can see in the figure there are no headers in the new chapters.

Comment: I tested your example alone, and it worked fine. I would upvote it if I could :D. The problem appeared when I tried to implement it into my document. Again to explain my problem after implementation: I renamed the 'Bibliography' into 'References', so that's where the name comes from. I do not know where this is set, but my headings are automatically added to the page header. I like that. But now, on the page after my references with the new three chapters, there is the header 'References' too. This is not wanted. I used \thispagestyle{plain} to fix this.

Comment: @the return of the thesis Perhaps you can add to your question a minimum code that shows the issue: the full preamble you are using plus some empty chapters.

Comment: @the return of the thesis I updated the answer with a chapter `References` before the specials chapters. There are no headers form previous chapter. Also added `hyperref` and generated the corrected links to `References` and the special chapters.

Comment: Thank you! The error is in my code.

Answer (score 0):

An answer to two of your questions.

```
% chapprob.tex  SE 637099

\documentclass{scrbook}

\let\saveclear\cleardoublepage

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

%%% stop chapters starting on another page
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{}

%% unnumbered chapter but added to ToC
\chapter*{Star 1} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Star 1}
Text

\chapter{Star 2}
Text

\chapter{Star 3}
Text

%% revert to normal chapter location
\let\cleardoublepage\saveclear

\chapter{Regular}
Text

\end{document}
```

I don't know how to remove a chapter number in the ToC, perhaps someone else does.

Comment: Wow, thank you! Does '\let\saveclear\cleardoublepage' have to be in the preamble, or can I put it before '\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{}'?

Comment: @thereturnofthethesis It need not be in the preamble but must be before the `\renewcommand...` To me it just makes it a bit more obvious being in the preamble.